# Parallelogram problem

Tags: analytic-geometry

ABCD is a parallelogram and A(-b,-a) ,B(a,-3 ),C(5,a), D(-2,a) are given find  the ratio of a/b

Comment: As the parallelogram makes to congruent triangle they should have the same areas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Opposite sides of a parallelogram are equal in length.

Therefore using the distance formula, we get:

$(a+b)^2+(a-3)^2=(7)^2$

$(5-a)^2 +(a+3)^2=(b-2)^2+(2a)^2$

You can solve these two equations to get the value of $a$ and $b$ and then find the necessary ratio.